# Как осуществить поиск по файлу Excel

Tags: c#, excel, таблицы

Нашел на сайтах информацию как открыть файл и конкретный лист, но не могу найти больше. Нужно найти конкретную ячейку по ее содержимому и вернуть ее координаты. Какими классами воспользоваться?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы работаете в среде **Visual Studio Community** и у вас установлен компонент **Набор средств Visual Studio  для Office (VSTO)**, то в библиотеке **Microsoft Object Library** есть метод **Find** объекта **Range** для поиска первой ячейки из диапазона, методы  **FindNext** и **FindPrevious** объекта **Range** для поиска следующей и предыдущей ячейки из диапазона.

Для вывода координат ячейки в формате $A$1 используйте Свойство **Cells.Adress** объекта **Range**.

Обратите внимание, что методы **FindNext** и **FindPrevious** возвращаются в исходную ячейку, поэтому  необходимо завершить цикл.

В вопросе необходимо указывать в какой среде вы работаете и с какими библиотеками, иначе получается что вопрос общий, а не конкретный и детализированный.

Comment: Спасибо, это избыточный ответ

Comment: Не очень понял вас, если честно. Сарказма не было, мне действительно хватило всей информации из вашего ответа. Прошу прощения, если мой комментарий показался вам неприятным. Избыточным я его назвал в хорошем смысле, дополнительной информации не требуется, все коротко и ясно